# Center an SVG inside a DIV

Tags: html, svg, sass

I have a div with an SVG inside it:

[image: whats wrong]

```css
.svg * {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo ball design">
  <svg class="svg pen" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
    <g>
      <path data-color="color-2" fill="#136f71" d="M5.586,15L15,5.586l-3.293-3.293c-0.391-0.391-1.023-0.391-1.414,0l-8,8 c-0.391,0.391-0.391,1.023,0,1.414L5.586,15z"></path>
      <rect data-color="color-2" x="7.636" y="10.636" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -5.9203 14.293)" fill="#136f71" width="13.313" height="7.314"></rect>
      <rect data-color="color-2" x="28.05" y="29.636" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -14.3761 34.707)" fill="#136f71" width="13.313" height="10.143"></rect>
      <path data-color="color-2" fill="#136f71" d="M44.085,35.329l-8.757,8.757l9.475,1.895C44.869,45.994,44.935,46,45,46 c0.263,0,0.518-0.104,0.707-0.293c0.236-0.236,0.339-0.575,0.273-0.903L44.085,35.329z"></path>
      <path fill="#136f71" d="M45.707,12.293l-10-10c-0.391-0.391-1.023-0.391-1.414,0l-5.291,5.291l2.706,2.709 c0.39,0.391,0.39,1.024-0.001,1.414C31.511,11.902,31.256,12,31,12c-0.256,0-0.512-0.098-0.708-0.293l-2.705-2.708l-3.584,3.584 l1.711,1.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C25.52,15.902,25.264,16,25.008,16s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293l-1.711-1.711 l-3.586,3.586l3.711,3.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C22.52,22.902,22.264,23,22.008,23s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293 l-3.711-3.711l-3.586,3.586l1.711,1.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C15.52,25.902,15.264,26,15.008,26 s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293l-1.711-1.711l-3.586,3.586l3.711,3.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414 C12.52,32.902,12.264,33,12.008,33s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293L7.59,28.996l-5.297,5.297c-0.391,0.391-0.391,1.023,0,1.414l10,10 C12.488,45.902,12.744,46,13,46s0.512-0.098,0.707-0.293l32-32C46.098,13.316,46.098,12.684,45.707,12.293z M38,16 c-1.105,0-2-0.895-2-2c0-1.105,0.895-2,2-2s2,0.895,2,2C40,15.105,39.105,16,38,16z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I want to center the SVG inside the div. Is this not the right way to center an SVG when it is in its "html-like" code form? (Not sure what it's called.)

I know I am targeting my sass correctly as `fill: red` is working.

Please Advise and let me know if you need to see more of my code, thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you wants to center `svg` shape inside `div`?

Comment: Or do you want to center div inside of body?

Comment: Center the svg inside the div, yes. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Make the div `position:relative` and the svg `position:absolute`
- For the svg give it `top:(calc 50% - 24px)` and `left:(50% - 24px)`

That's 50% of containing div's height minus half the height of svg and 50% of containing div's width minus half the width of svg. A `position:absolute` element (i.e. svg) boundaries are it's `position:relative` parent's (i.e. .foo) borders.

**SNIPPET**

```css
.svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 24px);
  left: calc(50% - 24px);
}
.foo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid brown;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo ball design">
  <svg class="svg pen" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
    <g>
      <path data-color="color-2" fill="#e00" d="M5.586,15L15,5.586l-3.293-3.293c-0.391-0.391-1.023-0.391-1.414,0l-8,8 c-0.391,0.391-0.391,1.023,0,1.414L5.586,15z"></path>
      <rect data-color="color-2" x="7.636" y="10.636" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -5.9203 14.293)" fill="#e00" width="13.313" height="7.314"></rect>
      <rect data-color="color-2" x="28.05" y="29.636" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -14.3761 34.707)" fill="#e00" width="13.313" height="10.143"></rect>
      <path data-color="color-2" fill="#e00" d="M44.085,35.329l-8.757,8.757l9.475,1.895C44.869,45.994,44.935,46,45,46 c0.263,0,0.518-0.104,0.707-0.293c0.236-0.236,0.339-0.575,0.273-0.903L44.085,35.329z"></path>
      <path fill="#136f71" d="M45.707,12.293l-10-10c-0.391-0.391-1.023-0.391-1.414,0l-5.291,5.291l2.706,2.709 c0.39,0.391,0.39,1.024-0.001,1.414C31.511,11.902,31.256,12,31,12c-0.256,0-0.512-0.098-0.708-0.293l-2.705-2.708l-3.584,3.584 l1.711,1.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C25.52,15.902,25.264,16,25.008,16s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293l-1.711-1.711 l-3.586,3.586l3.711,3.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C22.52,22.902,22.264,23,22.008,23s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293 l-3.711-3.711l-3.586,3.586l1.711,1.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C15.52,25.902,15.264,26,15.008,26 s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293l-1.711-1.711l-3.586,3.586l3.711,3.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414 C12.52,32.902,12.264,33,12.008,33s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293L7.59,28.996l-5.297,5.297c-0.391,0.391-0.391,1.023,0,1.414l10,10 C12.488,45.902,12.744,46,13,46s0.512-0.098,0.707-0.293l32-32C46.098,13.316,46.098,12.684,45.707,12.293z M38,16 c-1.105,0-2-0.895-2-2c0-1.105,0.895-2,2-2s2,0.895,2,2C40,15.105,39.105,16,38,16z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the svg as a class in css rather than an element in the DOM? Basically this svg will be part of the design, therefore I guess it should be in the css?

Comment: `.svg` is a class assigned to the svg tag. The OP's code involves a svg tag which is DOM and therefore a necessary aspect of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

try to use sudo-element approach to center the SVG vertically inside your div like:

```css
.svg * {
 
  fill: red;
       
}
.foo.ball{
   text-align:center;
   background-color:#333;
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
   margin:0 auto;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 20px solid  #945437;
}
.svg{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.foo.ball.design:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo ball design">
  <svg class="svg pen" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
    <g>
      <path data-color="color-2" fill="#136f71" d="M5.586,15L15,5.586l-3.293-3.293c-0.391-0.391-1.023-0.391-1.414,0l-8,8 c-0.391,0.391-0.391,1.023,0,1.414L5.586,15z"></path>
      <rect data-color="color-2" x="7.636" y="10.636" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -5.9203 14.293)" fill="#136f71" width="13.313" height="7.314"></rect>
      <rect data-color="color-2" x="28.05" y="29.636" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -14.3761 34.707)" fill="#136f71" width="13.313" height="10.143"></rect>
      <path data-color="color-2" fill="#136f71" d="M44.085,35.329l-8.757,8.757l9.475,1.895C44.869,45.994,44.935,46,45,46 c0.263,0,0.518-0.104,0.707-0.293c0.236-0.236,0.339-0.575,0.273-0.903L44.085,35.329z"></path>
      <path fill="#136f71" d="M45.707,12.293l-10-10c-0.391-0.391-1.023-0.391-1.414,0l-5.291,5.291l2.706,2.709 c0.39,0.391,0.39,1.024-0.001,1.414C31.511,11.902,31.256,12,31,12c-0.256,0-0.512-0.098-0.708-0.293l-2.705-2.708l-3.584,3.584 l1.711,1.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C25.52,15.902,25.264,16,25.008,16s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293l-1.711-1.711 l-3.586,3.586l3.711,3.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C22.52,22.902,22.264,23,22.008,23s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293 l-3.711-3.711l-3.586,3.586l1.711,1.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414C15.52,25.902,15.264,26,15.008,26 s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293l-1.711-1.711l-3.586,3.586l3.711,3.711c0.391,0.391,0.391,1.023,0,1.414 C12.52,32.902,12.264,33,12.008,33s-0.512-0.098-0.707-0.293L7.59,28.996l-5.297,5.297c-0.391,0.391-0.391,1.023,0,1.414l10,10 C12.488,45.902,12.744,46,13,46s0.512-0.098,0.707-0.293l32-32C46.098,13.316,46.098,12.684,45.707,12.293z M38,16 c-1.105,0-2-0.895-2-2c0-1.105,0.895-2,2-2s2,0.895,2,2C40,15.105,39.105,16,38,16z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The sudo-element is an element which is rendered on the run without writing it in your HTML it let you add many functionality around your main elements

and using this technique is one of many ways to align elements vertically, you can read more about it [here](http://w34.co/tutorials/6-ways-to-align-elements-vertically/)

using this approach is done on 2 steps step one is to add the sudo element to the container like:

```
.your_container_class:after{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and the second step is to add this two properties to the content you wish to center like:

```
.your_content_class{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**Important Note**

in oreder to let this work the container itself sholud have a height property like:

```
.your_container_class{
 height:100%/*or 200px; or any other height*/
}
```

Comment: Would love an explanation on this "sudo-element" approach; If you have the time. How and why is `:after` used in this? It looks odd, Maybe because I don't understand it. +1 for showing me something new

Answer (score 0):

SVG element should have a `display:block`, `width` and `margin:0 auto` applied to it, and not to the nested elements inside of it (*)

```
svg {
 width   : 200px;
 display : block;
 margin  : 0 auto;
}
```

update :

a more simple approach would be to use `text-align:center` on the holder div instead (svg still need width)

```
div{ text-align : center; }
```