# centering an SVG inside a div

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to display an SVG image inside a position:fixed div. I have

```
<div class="main">
  <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 180 100">
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#003300"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

and style

```
.main {
  position:fixed;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background: #33AAAA;
}

.svg {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:static;
}
```

I want to center the SVG horizontally and vertically. I get a strange behavior. Changing the size of the browser window, shows that when the svg is smaller than available width, it is weirdly placed. For example: [image: here] there is more space on the left than on the right.

Codepen (including CSS reset): [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwJmry)

Comment: you have  left: 100px; on main class. thats why your svg left is empty.

Comment: That is not the point. I want to center the dark green rectangle in the light one. Maybe the left has something to do...

Comment: The answer might be therehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822510/center-an-svg-inside-a-div?rq=1 I am testing it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I center an SVG in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639383/how-do-i-center-an-svg-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the width to 100%, then shifting it over by 100px. The width is still calculated as whatever the 100% width is. To center it the way you want, you will need to subtract 100px from the width or nest things differently.

```
.main {
  position:fixed;  
  left:100px;
  height: 100%;
  width:calc(100% - 100px);
  background: #33AAAA;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was figuring out that :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its because you have the `left: 100px` in your `main` class. If you take that out it centers correctly.

here is the main class that should work:

```
.main {
  position:fixed;  
  left:100px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: #33AAAA;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I do not want to have the light green to fill the whole viewport. I want to leave some space on the left for other things

Comment: In that case check out my edited answer. That should work if you adjust your `main` class to that.